# Perform data checks in azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have and ADF pipeline which reads data from an on-prem source and copies it to a dataset in azure.

I want to perform some datachecks:

1. If the data contains the features I need
2. If there is null in some features
3. If the feature is all nulls
   It should fail if the conditions above dnt meet

Is there a way to do this in data factory without using a batch service and just activities in data factory or maybe a dataflow.

Comment: Any update on this please?

Comment: No, I ended up doing checks using python.

Comment: Interesting, consider posting that as an answer and marking it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using Assert activities but for the scope of my work this wasn't enough!

Therefore, I ended up using python code for data checks.

However, assert activity servers better if your datacheck criteria is not hard as mine.

Comment: Are you able to provide a few simple examples?  I think that would be amazingly useful for other people viewing the question and I will upvote it.

Comment: It doesn't need to be your whole code or anything sensitive - just some examples of the type of data check you were doing.

Answer (score 1):

Many approaches to this you could do a traditional batch process running function/code in a process. You could weave together ADF activities into multiple steps combination of 'Lookup Activity' possibly followed by a 'Validation Activity' and 'Delete Activity' with your criteria and rules defined.

Azure Data Factory 'Data Flows' - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-overview - Allows you map out data transformation as data moves through the pipeline in a codeless fashion.

A pattern with ADF Data Flows is 'Wrangling Data Flows' to work with data and prepare it for consumption. Ref Article - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/wrangling-overview

Answer (score 1):

The [Copy activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview) in Azure Data Factory (ADF) or Synapse Pipelines provides some basic validation checks called '[data consistency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-data-consistency#:%7E:text=When%20you%20move%20data%20from,between%20source%20and%20destination%20store.)'.  This can do things like: fail the activity if the number of rows read from the source is different from the number of rows in the sink, or identify the number of incompatible rows which were not copied depending on the type of copy you are doing.

This is probably not quite at the level you want so you could look at writing something custom, eg using the [Stored Proc activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-stored-procedure), or looking at Mapping Data Flows and its [Assert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-assert) task which could do something like this.  There's a useful video in the link which shows the feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create data flows and apply conditional split activity. This will help you to achieve your scenario.
There is no such coding for this. This is diagrammatically you can do this in ADF or Azure Synapse Data Flow.

Find my attached data flow diagram that checks a few conditions like when the year is less than the specified year or if data in a column is null, date format, etc.

[image]